# Did the Issa ally themselves with the Italians or with Ethiopia in the 1930?

Tags: 20th-century, africa, italy, 1930s, ethiopia

Did the [Issa](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Issa_(clan)&oldid=1199020540#20th_Century%E2%80%93present) ally themselves with the Italians or with Ethiopia in the 1930? I found conflicting statements about this. Wikipedia claims without an immediate citation [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Issa_(clan)&oldid=1199020540#20th_Century%E2%80%93present):

> In the Italian invasion of Ethiopia in 1935/36, Issa fought on the Italian side, in return benefited from weapons and military training and lucrative marketing opportunities for their cattle.

OTOH, a [source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43660335) cited later on by Wikipedia (for another fact) claim the opposite happened:

> The Issa peculiarity for acting independently of the other Somali clans was exhibited in the
> mid-1930s, when they took the part of Ethiopia against the Italians. All other
> [Somali] groups collaborated actively with the Italian invader. In 1947 all of
> the Somali clans in the Ogaden and the Reserved Areas, with the exception of
> the Issa, petitioned British authorities not to have their lands surrendered to
> Ethiopia.

So, which side were the Issa on, in the Italian-Ethiopia conflict?

Comment: A source [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=9as3AAAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT146&dq=issa%20italian%20invasion%201935&pg=PT146#v=onepage&q=issa%20italian%20invasion%201935&f=false)  seems to agree with the earlier entry. The JSTOR article appears to cite *Islam in Ethiopia* by Trimingham. So far i find no searchable copies of that work. One image-only copy with full access at [Archive ,org](https://archive.org/details/islam-in-ethiopia-j-spencer-trimingham/page/137/mode/2up?q=italy) doesn't seem to mention the Issa directly-but as I said, no search so...

Comment: @justCal: I found that book too. On a quick lookup, it's written by an Ethiopian professor (of political science), but that's no reason to dismiss it, although it probably has some biases. Anythow, neither that nor Clarke are in-depth history sources about the 1930s. Both make rather passing remarks about that era, while their main focus is on more recent events.

Comment: @justCal: As for what biases I mean, the next para in Kefale's book is what I'd call a standard litany of complaints that the Afar were evicted (by the Issa) from certain regions. Another [source](https://academicjournals.org/journal/IJSA/article-full-text/CB045F552521) says something a bit more surprising: "Archival sources of the Italian occupation period  ....

Comment: @justCal: ".... showed the scale, immensity, frequency and organization of Issa-Afar violence reached crisis level to be critical security concern of the occupying force that it desperately resorted to play the role of neutral arbiter." It's not coming from an Italian [or even a Westerner], so can't be easily dismissed as apologizing Italian imperialism. I suppose the Italians regretted arming the locals once they started fighting each other more than the Italians had anticipated/desired.